# Pause listenning to mouse/ key events until a sound is finished

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, onclicklistener, keyboard-events

In my game, if I select the good answer I play an applause sound then I move to the next question. So after calling a method say `validate()`in `setOnMousePressed`, I play the `wav` and do this :

```
try {
     Thread.sleep(1700);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To pause everything until the sound is finished, then I call a method `reset()` to move to the next question.

The problem occurs when I click more than one time before 1700ms passes. At the next questions even without clicking anymore, it takes in count all the excess previous clicks and procceed to `validate()`and `reset()`so the final result is a hot mess.

How can I pause listening to mouse/key events until the sound is finished?

Comment: Wrap it with a `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

As Yahya mentioned, simply declare a boolean for e.g.

```
boolean listenForMouseEvents = true;
```

Set an if condition such that `validate()` can only be invoked when `listenForMouseEvents` is true for e.g.

```
if (listenForMouseEvents) {
  validate();
}
```

Then once you click, set the `listenForMouseEvents` to false.